# Soap service SSL/TSL certificate error only in one PC

Tags: vb.net, soap, ssl-certificate

I have and old app made it in VB.NET 2010.
The App have a GUI and connect to a SOAP service(asmx) on a remote server that runs on HTTPS connection.
A few weeks ago the service provider just changed the web address so I updated the app and works ok in my PC, where VB.NET is installed, and also on a PC that never had that App installed before. But when I try to run the App in the PC that has had that app running for years; it does not work; instead I get this error.

*Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority....*

I think that probably is a .config or a .xml file that the older App created and is messing something.
I also tried disabling the Windows 7 firewall with no luck.

Any clue please?

**EDIT:**
I just sniffed the connection and the PC that doesn't validate the certificate is trying to get some cab from

.GET /msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab

Comment: What OS is installed on that old PC? Is it Win7 as implied by _"I also tried disabling the Windows 7 firewall"_? If so, you're potentially seeing an issue with the service provider upgrading to use TLS > 1.0, which Windows 7 doesn't support. You need to [manually install and configure it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392) on Windows 7.

Comment: If the App (Client) is third party product you have to install NET 4.8 on that machine otherwise if that is a your own product you have to put this `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` in your code at the top of the method that call the web service. Also change the building target to 4.7 >  framework

Comment: @HelO'Ween All the 3 PC's have W7 OS. Two of them works one not. I will check your link anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj I didn't created a method, I just added a service reference in the left tree and VS 2010 do all the "magic" creating all the methods.  So, where I should change that, is a .vb, .svcinfo, .disco, .wsdl, .svcmap, .config or a .xml file?

Comment: @HelO'Ween Since is a 32bit OSI tried to update KB3140245 from Microsoft Catalog and get "This update isn't applicable to this PC." I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure it's 32 bit? Try this PowerShell `(Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture`. If it is 32 bit, check the installed updates. Scroll also down the MS page and make sure you apply these necessary registry changes.

Comment: @HelO'Ween I just added more info at the end of the post. It rings any bell to you? For me seems like it needs some update. Yes is a 32 bits OS.

Comment: @E_Blue: that should be the [Trusted Root Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265983(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Which begs the obvious question: is that Windows 7 up to date concerning all Windows Updates?

Comment: No, is not updated from December 2019. I'm trying to but I'm getting errors when Windows Update try to update Net Framework 4.8